# Cant see first page on google pagespeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

When I give URL of my site to the google pagespeed service,I get all the values of the different metrics that the service provides.

The problem is that I can't see the page of my site,on the right-hand side div,which is supposed to show the page.And therefore my client can't see the page too.As you can guess the client is giving me complaints of something which he shouldn't really be so much fussed about.

Note:The site is made on angular1.Also,angular routing is injected and used.So when user moves from one URL to another,a fade in style occurs.Angular developers will know about this style.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ng-enter {
      transition:0.5s linear all;
      opacity:0;
    }

    /* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
    .ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
      opacity:1;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: give him a screenshot with the page append it to that frame and tell him the problem is in his browser :)))

Comment: The problem is just the animation, or it arises because you're building SPA?

Comment: @madalinivascu That's a good idea :) But the client talks on skype and share screens :(

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I am asking the question here :) But the site is SPA.

Comment: is your score lower because of the animation what problem does it goth if the picture there is blank ?

Comment: @madalinivascu no the score is actually pretty high.Problem is that the page is not shown on the right hand div where it should be shown.Adding a screen shot.Have added a screen shot.Please advise me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: man that's high, lol dumb client explain to him that the blank image doesn't mean anything

Comment: @madalinivascu So you are telling me that there is no way the page speed service will show the page.I wanted to know why?The client is fussing about it.

Comment: man that just a screenshot it doesn't offer any valuable information

Comment: did you try to remove the transition and see if the page appears ?

Comment: @madalinivascu yes have removed the style but still google pagespeed doesnt show it.